# Clarification on the BigQuery materialized view documentation

Tags: google-bigquery

I am reading the limitation section Google Cloud BigQuery documenation on Materialized views. One of the bullet points reads from this link

"https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#limitations"  reads as.

> "The view SQL cannot be updated after the materialized view is created"

I understood this as, we cannot alter/replace the materialized view with new underlying code

however, materialized view supports `CREATE or REPLACE` based on this documentation

```
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_materialized_view_statement
```

and that I was able to modify the materialized view using CREATE OR REPLACE.

Therefore, my question is what does the limitation in the block quote exactly trying to convey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what they mean:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTnQA.png)

[Materialized View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y6fM.png)

Comment: Thank you for contributing. However, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

They are referring to the attributes/columns of a Materialized view, which cannot be changed in case you want to add or delete any column name or their datatype.

Answer (score 1):

I think updating the existing table definition is not allowed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).